# Error in OCJP exam simulation: how many objects are really created?

Tags: java

In a simulation for a the OCJP certification I found this question:

```
1. StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer("abc");
2. StringBuffer s2 = s1;
3. StringBuffer s3 = new StringBuffer("abc");

How many objects are created ?
```

They state that the correct answer is 4 because they state:

```
s1 is one object, s2 is another object, 
s3 is another object and "abc" is another String Object .
```

But for me it's wrong and it should be 3, because `s1` and `s2` are the same object. What do you think?

Comment: If that's really what it said, then you should stop using that website.

Comment: Yes, that should be 3. At least for my knowledge

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but copy constructor?

Comment: A copy constructor is not called on the assignement like in C++. In Java I think you should do something like MyClass s2 = new MyClass(s1);

Comment: Please post the link to the offending website so we can avoid it.

Comment: This is the offending website: http://www.techfaq360.com/scjp7IIsuccesskit.jsp They sell 600 questions for just 19 dollars, but questions and answers are full of grammatical errors.

Comment: OCJP certification is bad, because it works only in one direction.

Comment: What do you mean, Roman?

Comment: To be pedantic, it's impossible to know. The StringBuffer constructor could create as many objects as it wants under the hood.

Comment: The grammatical errors alone should have put you off the site. How the *questions* can have grammatical errors when they should be straight from the OCJP exam is a mystery to me.

Comment: The site claims "Verified Answers Researched by Industry Experts and almost 100% correct"!

Answer (score 8):

You are right that the answer is not 4 objects.

However, the question "how many objects are created" is ambiguous.  The issue is that one of the three objects is not created when you execute the code.  Specifically, the `String` object that corresponds to the `"abc"` literal is *actually* created when the code is loaded.  When that code is executed, two `StringBuffer` objects are created, and the pre-existing `String` object is used.

And in fact it is more complicated than that, since at class load time it is possible that another temporary `String` object is created and then discarded after it has been interned;

- If an `"abc"` literal has already been loaded in a different class, then that one will be used.
- It is not specified if the string pool implementation makes a fresh copy of the `String` if it needs to put it into the pool.

Unless the question is more precisely stated, there is no single correct answer.  The best you can say is:

- Two `StringBuffer` objects are created when the code is run.
- One or two `String` objects are created when the code is loaded.

Then there is the issue of whether you should count the private `char[]` objects that form part of the `StringBuffer` and `String` objects.  That could inflate the object count to as much as 8.

Comment: Agreed. The question is ill-formed. Also pointless. If the OCJP really contains any questions about how many objects are created, they should be removed. I've never asked or been asked such a question in an interview, and I would form a pretty poor opinion of any interviewer who did so. Given the existence of garbage collection, and given the question's reliance on aspects of the JLS that most programmers won't have read, it is basically a complete irrelevance. +1

Comment: @EJP SCJP contained such questions, but never this kind of corner case (classes that may instantiate other things internally, String constant pool, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Yes definitely 3 Object.both s1 and s2 referring same location. so s1, s2 and "abc" are the objects here. May be it is better not to follow that reference.

Comment: You were right the first time. Don't be bashful about it.

Comment: he is in fact wrong, at least in potentio. An instance of Class<StringBuffer> is also created, and an instance of Class<String>. Internally StringBuffer no doubt creates instances of stuff as well, and instances of their Class<Xxx>.

Comment: @jwenting Both those class instances are created when the class containing this code is loaded, not when the code in the OP is executed.

Comment: @EJP true, but he never mentioned the scope of the question :)

Answer (score 4):

**CORRECTION**

There should be 3 objects:

```
1. StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer("abc");
```

Two objects will be created in memory s1 & "abc" . This is because, strings are interned and literals are added to a memory pool.

```
2. StringBuffer s2 = s1;
```

No object will be created here because s2 will point to "abc" created as part of s1

```
3. StringBuffer s3 = new StringBuffer("abc");
```

Only one object will be create for s3.

Comment: Umm, won't the string interning mean that there'll only be one `"abc"` in memory?

Comment: But it's a string literal, not a `new String`.

Comment: He's *not* 'creating a string object with the new operator'. He's creating a StringBuffer with an existing String as argument. The correct answer is 3. -1

Comment: Apologies guys for spreading the wrong information. I have tried to correct my answer. Feel free to provide more comments.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth is right, both "abc" are literal Strings at compile time, they will be the same object at run time.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I was confused and I post a new question related to this to avoid harm here. I got lot of downvote and your incorrect answer got lots of upvote that time

Comment: @Ruchira You deserve an upvote :-) The problem with your answer was that you didn't try to explain things. Just saying 3 was not convincing people. And i somehow convinced few people with wrong info ;-)

Comment: @JunedAhsan yes. Some how now every thing is fine :)

Comment: Good correction but downvote remains, as there is no relevant specification of how many objects `new StringBuffer()` itself creates, and there is at least one: a `char[].` Contrary to my comment above, the correct answer is 'unspecified'.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
1. StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer("abc");
```

1 `builder` object + 1 `char[]` object + (1 String literal, if created)

```
2. StringBuffer s2 = s1;
```

No new objects.

```
3. StringBuffer s3 = new StringBuffer("abc");
```

1 `builder` object + 1 `char[]` object

A `StringBuilder` *encapsulates* the backing char[] inside, which *is* an object.

As @StephenC says the question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

3 or 4, depending on implementation.  Some compilers would create only one String object for the constant "abc" and reference it as many times as necessary, and other compilers would create one object per constant.  AFAIK, this has not been mandated by all the languages specification versions, and it could change again in the future.

Or more, depending on StringBuffer's implementation (which could actively create a char[] and copy the initialization String, as opposed to a lazy implementation that postpones this until the StringBuffer's contents are really changed).  Again, this should not be mandated by the language.  And, BTW, do arrays count as `Object`s for the purpose of the question?  And what if a StringBuffer implementation stored information in a JNI structure?  What that count as objects?  I'm just trying to re-inforce my point about non-language-mandated implementation details.

A test should not ask this kind of questions unless it is about a specific implementation and/or JLS version.

What is absolutely clear is that the **reason** they give for their answer of 4 is completely incorrect.  The assignment to `s2` does not cause any new object to be created.

Comment: Not correct. Java compilers are required by the JLS and the JVM Specification to pool string literals.

Comment: @EJP  The JLS has changed in time, even in this particular respect.  When I say "The Language" I don't mean the last version of the JLS, nor the next.  I'll try to be clearer in my answer, though.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such change. Please provide a citation. As far as I know the basic answer to questions of this form but involving only Strings and literals hasn't changed at all since 1997.

Comment: I know this pretty well, because long ago (very early days of Java), I developed a Java course.  The first edition of this course covered Java 1.0.1.  To demonstrate how `String`s were created, I used a small sample program.  Well, I have had to **change** my sample program (and the surrounding explanation) 1 or 2 times, usually **while** giving the course.  Of course I remember it!  :-)