# Confuse what is the difference between two cases?

Tags: java, object

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297919/error-in-ocjp-exam-simulation-how-many-objects-are-really-created/18297948#18297948) SO question.

My first question is as far as I can understand number of objects are `3`, `s1, s3 and "abc"` (I posted an answer to this question). If some one says it is `4`. How that happens there?

consider my following class.

```
public class ObjectCount {
    static int i;

    ObjectCount() {
        System.out.println(++i);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ObjectCount obj1 = new ObjectCount();  //i=1
        ObjectCount obj2 = new ObjectCount(); //i=2
        ObjectCount obj3 = obj1; // obj3 is also an object refer same as obj1   
    }
}
```

How many objects are there? again I think it should be `2`. So how above SO post answer can be 4 objects?can some one help me to figure it out where I get some point incorrect?

*FYI :*
 Now previous issue has fixed on that post. Incorrect answer has made correct. It is 3 object there. No need to worry.

Comment: `obj1`, `obj2` and `obj3` are references, not objects.

Comment: I think everyone on the other question agreed that there are only 3 objects created, so what's the point of this follow-up? Maybe I miss the essence of your question, but it feels like you're asking exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 variables `obj1`, `obj2`, and `obj3`. However, you have 2 objections `new ObjectCount();`that were ever created.

Comment: you are correct, But This is not the answer for my question, please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

The number of times the constructor is called = number of objects

That is 2. However there are 3 references to Object count objects.

> obj1 -----> 1st Object
>
> obj2 -----> 2nd Object
>
> obj3 -----> 2nd Object

Comment: you are correct,But This is not the answer for my question, please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

[If you see docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html%27)

> The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor.
>
> Note: The phrase "instantiating a class" means the same thing as "creating an object." When you create an object, you are creating an "instance" of a class, therefore "instantiating" a class.

Assuming,you are reffering to `references` not `objects` ,There fore you created only two `Objects`.

Comment: you are correct.But This is not the answer for my question,please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

2 objects.  The first with only one reference (from local variable `obj1`), and the second with two references (from local variables `obj2` and `obj3`).

Regarding to your answer to the original question, I tend to agree.  String "abc" would be created as an object only once, and referenced as many times as necessary.  This was true at least in the first few versions of Sun's JDK.  However, AFAIK this behavior is **not mandated** by the language, so the answer should be "3 or 4, depending on the implementation" (in fact, some crazy implementations could create even more).  People who answered "4" was probably thinking of a different (more modern?) implementation.

Comment: you are correct,But this is not the answer for my question, read my question again.

Comment: If your question is "How many objects are there?", I would say it's completely ambiguous.  In particular, if you assume that the program has completely executed the correct answer would be 0.  In the first paragraph of my answer I try to give a reasonable response, assuming that immediately after initialization of obj3.

Comment: On the second paragraph, I try to attend to your other questions.  Unfortunately, the scenarios are not comparable because 1)  In the other question there are constant objects involved (used to initialize yet more objects), and 2) Those constant objects happen to be String's, which are treated much differently than regular objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is to object of type ObjectCount. ObjectCount have an int that is static so it's total of three objects.

When it comes to the other SO question it is also three object because the JVM is reusing the string object. If they had used new String("abc") then they would have had 4 object. In your example all the ObjectCount objects are using the same instance of the integer.